# Checkout Totals Sort Order not visible in my magento admin panel

Tags: magento2, checkout

I can't see 'Checkout Totals Sort Order' (https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-totals-sort-order.html) option under sales tab in my magento 2.3 admin panel

Answer (score 2):

you have to select default config in store view selection at the top left of the page please see the screenshot

[image]